# ANTLR @members and lexer

Tags: antlr

i have problem with @members rule in ANTLR. I want overwrite default error handling, so i read http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Error+reporting+and+recovery and write this simple code for my grammar:

```
@members {
   def displayRecognitionError(self, tokenNames, e):
      print 'Test'
}
```

I have no @lexer::members or @parser::members in my grammar. Code (python runtime) from this rule is included only in parser file, not in lexer. It is a bug? I think it is, @members should add content to both - lexer and parser according to documentation. I use Python runtime, 3.1.3.

Btw. is stackoverflow inline code work's for Opera?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a combined grammar file, `@members` is a short-hand for `@parser::members`.

```
// combined grammar
grammar Foo;

@members {
  // only parser members here, equivalent to: @parser::members { ... }
}

@lexer::members {
  // lexer members
}
```

When you use separate lexer- and/or parser grammars, then `@members` is enough:

```
parser grammar Foo;

@members {
  // parser members
}
```

or

```
lexer grammar Foo;

@members {
  // lexer members
}
```

> *Galmi wrote:*
>
> Btw. is stackoverflow inline code work's for Opera?

I guess so, but questions about SO itself can be asked on [SO-Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).